# I can't call my button, it gives me error "Unresolved Reference"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So my problem is, when I try to call my button it doesn't work and gives me an error saying "Unresolved Reference":

Calling the button:
[image]

Button on XML:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your button in the Kotlin file, MainActivity.kt or whatever you named it.

```
Button btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {

    }
});
```

This is in Java because I don't know Kotlin, but hopefully it's easy to translate.

Also note: you can add codeblocks in your question. Please do so as it makes it convenient for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

open build.gradle in Gradle Scripts
and add this
`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'`
to plugins

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```